# could someone please explain to me what the @"" has to do with the System.IO.Path.Combine method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file-io, directory-structure, .net

Let's say I have a folder like ClientBin in my Visual Studio C# Web Application.

I'm confused as to what the @"" will do in the following C# code that tries to create a path to a Directory:

```
String DirectoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"" + "ClientBin");
```

Or when it comes to fa file like in the following example:

```
String FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine("admin", "access", @"" + "users.aspx");
```

Basically, could someone please explain to me what the  @"" has to do with the  System.IO.Path.Combine method?

Comment: This is used for or as a LITERAL  also lets say that you have a file path that's "C:\mypath\myfile.txt" this would not be able to be read because of the return characters but putting the @ in front of the path resolves to a literal path..does this make sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `@` <strike>means that any escape character sequences are ignored and the string is taken as it is written</strike>. Not quite, see the link below.

> @"C:\temp\file.txt"

is the same as

> "C:\\temp\\file.txt"

In the second case \\ sequence means escaped backslash character.

**update**: dtb is right about that

see [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Not quite. It means that different escape character sequences are used.

Comment: @dtb - the only character that must be escaped is a double-quote.

Comment: @dtb - thanks for mentioning, used that for years and didn't know that

Answer (score 8):

In this case, it does absolutely nothing (probably caused by an extremely misguided programmer somewhere along the way). Normally, an `@` before a string specifies a verbatim string literal, where backslashes are no longer treated as escape characters.

Here, `@"" + "ClientBin"` is precisely equal to `"" + "ClientBin"`, which is of course equal to just `"ClientBin"`.

Verbatim string literals are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

`@""` is a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) (also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx), which basically means that backslashes and newlines are taken verbatim rather than parsed.  The usage is normally something like `@"\ClientBin"` or `@"[a-b]\*"`.  The way the code you show is using it is quite nonsensical, as `@""` and `""` are both the empty string, and you'd get the same result by simply writing `"ClientBin"`.

Answer (score 1):

A @ prefix is a [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but in the examples you provided, I don't think it has any effect; a verbatim @"" is equivalent to a normal "".

Edit: In case you're confused as to what verbatim strings are, what they essentially allow you to do is to represent a string without having to worry about escape sequences - for example, \n will NOT render as a new line in a verbatim string, but rather as the actual string \n. To represent a new line, you actually to make a new line in code
like this.

Answer (score 1):

@ tells the compiler to not treat any characters in the following string literal as special.

for example if you have "C:\Temp\users.aspx" the compiler will try and treat \T and \u as special chars (like \r\n is the carriage return,line feed), and will probably fail at run-time.

If you didn't have the @, you would have to change your string to

```
"C:\\Temp\\users.aspx"
```

which is ugly and hard to read IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple explanation if you are interested in viewing

The @ symbol serves 2 purposes in C#:

The first is that it allows you to use a reserved keyowrd as a variable like this:

```
int @int = 15;
```

The second option lets you specify a string without having to excape any characters. For instance the '\' character is an escape character so typically you would need to do this:

```
var myString = "c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt"
```

alternatively you can do this:

```
var myString = @"c:\myFolder\myfile.txt"
```